# Can I use a PWA to cache a small website?

Tags: web-applications, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a mobile design containing roughly 100 paragraphs of text divided over the website. It's tiny.

I want to have it working as offline webapp. When users have opened the content the  website should be able to function near flawlessly during inflight (no wifi) situations.

I've been reading a bit about PWA's and most of it is about caching the stylesheets and scripts. Do I perhaps pass the paragraphs through a script? Any light on the subject would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely achieve what you're looking for with a Service Worker.

I guess your paragraphs are in a html file, correct? SW can cache any static assets so the html that references both scripts and stylesheets can also be cached.

Depending on how deeply you would like to dive into PWA details, you could only use a simple library like UpUp https://www.talater.com/upup/ or start off by reading Google's introduction to the technology https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/service-workers

This could also be helpful https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lab-caching-files-with-service-worker